# Testing: how to access "model_has_error_on_field"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I was looking at Mastodon tests for inspiration, and I noticed this `model_has_error_on_field` method on their [User model tests](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/8603a075049a9e903b05e2370cf4c5ebfda1e703/spec/models/user_spec.rb#L34).

Anyone know from where this method is defined and how could I access it in my test suite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it's a custom `Rspec::Matchers` defined in [mastodon/spec/support/matchers/model/model_have_error_on_field.rb](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/8603a075049a9e903b05e2370cf4c5ebfda1e703/spec/support/matchers/model/model_have_error_on_field.rb)

---

If you want to use it:

- create [spec/support/matchers/model/model_have_error_on_field.rb](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/8603a075049a9e903b05e2370cf4c5ebfda1e703/spec/support/matchers/model/model_have_error_on_field.rb)
- `require` it inside `spect/rails_helper.rb` by uncommenting the line:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spect', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: [Shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) also has a bunch of swanky matchers that lets you write stuff like  `it { should validate_uniqueness_of :email }` if you want to up your game.

Comment: Indeed that's really handy, thanks !